# website shows only text in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox

Looking for help. I have built two website and it only shows text in firefox. Works fine with all other browsers.

Website works fine locally in my syste, When i upload all files to the hosting server it stops working ony for firefox. Is there anything i should do in htaccess or css or html to make it work?

dinmarcopolo.com
oceankidsdance.com

Both the sites are not displaying properly in firefox browser. Check in different systems and different locations. Need help in rectifying this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Windows backslash (`\`) in your file paths. Switch those to forward slashes (`/`), and you should be good to go.

Blink/Webkit-based browsers don't particularly care about which slashes you use, but Firefox is strict about it.

Change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\plugins\bootstrap.css">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/plugins/bootstrap.css">
```

Do that for all resource-paths.

Note that you'll also need the leading slash at the beginning of each path.